# Which is best for perfomance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Which of the following code snippets performs fastest?

```
if(ClassTestBase is ClassTestChild1)
```

or

```
if(ClassTestBase.Type == EClassType.Child1)
```

#### Update:

Here is the full scenario:

```
public enum EInheritanceTree
{
    BaseClass,
    Child1,
    Child2,
    Child3
}

public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual EInheritanceTree MyClassType
    {
         get
         {
              return EInheritanceTree.BaseClass;
         }
    }
}

public vlasse MyChildClass1 : MyBaseClass
{
    public override EInheritanceTree MyClassType
    {
        get
        {
            return EInheritanceTree.Child1;
        }
    }
}
```

Consider a method that has to compare the class type to see what kind it is. Which is the best?

```
public bool IsChild1(MyBaseClass myClass)
{
     if(myClass is MyChildClass1)
          return true;

     return false;
}
```

or

```
public bool IsChild1(MyBaseClass myClass)
{
     if(myClass.MyClassType == EInheritanceTree.Child1)
          return true;

     return false;
}
```

Comment: As those two pieces of code do different think, I don't see the advantage of comparing their performance.

Comment: Downvoted because of poor title, lack of tag indicating platform, and the fact that the two pieces of code do entirely different things.

Comment: It's a micro-optimization. Generally, if your program would benefit from such micro-optimizations, you would know how to figure out which performs best ;-)

Comment: Dont think the second line would even compile. If you are trying to compare the child type to the base type, then result will always be false. The two lines are used distinctively and no point of comparing their performance.

Comment: Wow, I hope none of these comments are from people who don't believe in comments "because the code should be self explanatory". That said, I did understand the question just from the 2 lines originally compared ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using a profiler to test which is more performant yourself? Visual Studio comes with a profiler.

I would be more concerned about the need to have an enum that hold inheritance information about your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about performance, don't wrap all this in functions. Any code that says:

```
if (Obj.IsChild1() ) foo;
```

Should just do:

```
if(myClass.MyClassType == EInheritanceTree.Child1) foo;
```

If you're worried about the performance, any notions you may have that says to hide everything behind functions needs to be revisited. Also, why don't you just use polymorphism - that's the "right" way to make subclasses act differently.

Regardless, do some timing of your own. It's the only way to be certain which is faster.

Comment: Also, if he is worried about this kind performance then c# is probably the wrong language as you will have more overhead in a managed language then in a unmanaged one.

Comment: @Mattias Jakobsson - agreed. But sometimes you're stuck with a language for other reasons.

Comment: -1: Method calls don't necessarily cost anything, because the compiler may inline a copy of the method. You should not do this unless you have profiler data confirming that it is a problem.

Comment: @JørgenFogh - key words in your comment are "don't necessarily" and "may". I contend you should not use the functions unless you have verified they don't hurt performance. And I did say to do timing in my answer. I also qualified the entire answer with "if you're worried about performance".

Comment: @phkaler: By your reasoning, I should pay the cost (in programmer time) up front, unless I can *prove* that I don't get a return (in computer time). That doesn't make sense to me. Code should be written to be readable and then optimized, if necessary. He might want to omit the call to make the code more readable, but whenever you mangle your code without a good reason, you're in trouble.

Comment: @JørgenFogh - I agree, mangling code needs to have a reason. I actually consider hiding simple checks like this behind function definitions annoying - UNLESS you use them a lot and the implementation is likely to change. Going all in with encapsulation and hiding is also paying a price up front - you assume it will help at a later date, and you assume the compiler is going to fix the potential performance issues. ;-)